# Image / ImageField / ImageCache (automatic thumbnails)

Tags: 7, media, nodes

I'm getting pretty frustrated here:

I'm a complete newbie with Drupal, just installed some modules like CCK, and made a new Content Type for my website to display products (no webshop purpose, just displaying them).
It also has an image field, for the user to upload an image, but what I'm trying to do here is have a thumbnail somehow automatically created (to display in the overview).

It seems like such a simple thing which every CMS should be able to do easily (and I'm sure it's possible) but I just don't know how it's done.

After googling quite a while I found a lot of articles on the subject however they all seem to refer to modules such as ImageCache, ImageField, and after some research about the mentioned modules it seems to me they have somehow been merged into one module: Image in Drupal 7.7

This is driving me crazy, and I would very much like to hear a simple explanation on how to get to the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that will walk you through adding images.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0I5f9YmmI0

Comment: this one is D7.

Comment: there are a TON of tutorials (D7) at http://nodeone.se/ (views, rules, etc) and http://buildamodule.com/drupal-camps-calendar has all of the Drupal Camps/Cons and most of them have the session videos online.  I learned a lot by watching them.

Answer (score 0):

To Drupal 6 [here is a tutorial](http://hanief.blogspot.com/2010/02/drupal-image-cck-field-imagecache.html) using CCK, Imagefield, Imagecache, Lightbox2 ad Views Modules. When you have installed these modules, follow the tutorial (there are few steps).

Here is [another tutorial](http://www.learndrupalcms.com/how-to-make-a-photo-gallery-with-thumbnails-in-drupal) with more detail.

Comment: ..Altough, if you are starting with Drupal, I think that the best way is Drupal 7.

Comment: Yep, I was specifically talking about 7 (but maybe not clearly enough, sorry for that)